# how to set Sony a7rii to save as raw, not jpg

Tags: raw, sony-alpha

I can't find out how to set a Sony a7rii to save as raw, not jpg. The hard copy manual doesn't help, and I haven't found out anything on Google either.

Help appreciated.

Comment: 5s on Google should bring up the PDF manual. There you can search for RAW and will immediately find it amongst quality settings.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It was under the first `MENU` tab > 1 > Quality.

Not an obvious place to put it to me.

Comment: Pretty much every digital camera I've ever used has the settings for the output format(s)  and size(s) under *Image Quality*.